# Сортировка TreeSet в обратном порядке

Tags: java

Подскажите как отсортировать TreeSet в обратном порядке.
Если просто Set можно сделать так:

```
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(5);
    list.add(59);
    list.add(21);
    Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder());
    Set resultSet = new LinkedHashSet(list);
    return resultSet;
```

а как сделать тоже самое только для TreeSet?

Comment: TreeSet(Comparator<? super E> comparator)

Comment: А если вам нужно уже существующий отсортировать: NavigableSet<E> descendingSet()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать [descendingSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#descendingSet--)

```
TreeSet <Integer>treeadd = new TreeSet<Integer>();
TreeSet <Integer>treereverse = new TreeSet<Integer>();

// Добавляем данные
treeadd.add(1);
treeadd.add(13);
treeadd.add(17);
treeadd.add(2);

// разворачиваем
treereverse = (TreeSet)treeadd.descendingSet();
```